# Running JAR games natively on desktop

Tags: java, jar, java-me

Is it possible to run old JAR games, the ones that used to run on nokia feature phones, natively on desktop without an emulator?

I figured it should be able to run on any device that has JRE but I'm not sure.

Comment: The base Java language is cross-platform, but apps were still coded for certain keypad inputs and often use a device-specific library or device-specific features, so the simple answer is no, you will most likely need an emulator for most old phone games. Note also that old phone apps would have been built in Java 6 or earlier and are no longer supported by the latest versions of Java, so you'll need to make sure you use an older JRE to run them.

Comment: I'd start with https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2008/02/14/run-mobile-midlets-on-your-pc/